# Amazon EC2 resize root device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, resize, root

I have one amazonw ec2 instance and would like to extend root device device form 100G to 500G. After create a new 500G volume and reattached to instance.
I can see volume is there by command $lsblk. However, after I resize the disk. I cannot do it with error "The filesystem is already 26212055 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

```
name@ip-172-1-1-3:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           799M  840K  798M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       99G   92G  3.1G  97% /
name@ip-172-1-1-3:~$ lsblk
NAME                              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE       
MOUNTPOINT
xvda                              202:0    0   500G  0 disk
└─xvda1                           202:1    0   100G  0 part /
name@ip-172-1-1-3:~$sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 26212055 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I follow @error2007s step 12 with "a" a #Toggle the bootable flag stop and reboot. I can not bring up instance.

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders, total 1048576000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1            2048  1048575999   524286976   83  Linux

Command (m for help): a
Partition number (1-4): 1

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
name@ip-172-1-1-3:~$ reboot
reboot: Need to be root
name@ip-172-1-1-3:~$ sudo reboot

Broadcast message from name@ip-172-1-1-3
    (/dev/pts/1) at 10:18 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
$ ssh -i "a.pem" name@ec2-172.1.1.3.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 22
ssh: connect to host ec2-172.1.1.3.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

here's exactly what to do:

`df -h` #print the name of your boot partition

`lsblk` #show info on all your block devices

You'll see from that output what the name of the disk is of your root partition. For example, you probably see something like this:

`xvde                               202:64   0   32G  0 disk 
└─xvde1                            202:65   0   8G  0 part /`

Our goal is to make `xvde1` use the whole available space from `xvde`.
Here's how to resize your partition:

`fdisk /dev/xvda` (the disk name, not your partition)
This enters into the `fdisk` utility.

1. `u` #Change the display to sectors
2. `p` #Print info
3. `d` #Delete the partition
4. `n` #New partition
5. `p` #Primary partition
6. `1` #Partition number
7. `2048` #First sector
8. Press Enter to accept the default
9. `p` #Print info
10. `a` #Toggle the bootable flag
11. `1` #Select partition 1
12. `w` #Write table to disk and exit

Now, reboot your instance:
`reboot`

After it comes back do:

`resize2fs /dev/xvde1` (the name of your partition, not the block device)

And finally verify the new disk size: 
`df -h`

Comment: Reboot your instance from dashboard

Comment: the issue is finally resolved. After taking deeper look, it turn out my sector/cylinders start from 16065/2 for some reason. So I recreated a new volume based on the same snapshot and then attached. Following the same steps but change cylinders# from 1 to 2. then i am able to bring up instance and use resize2fs

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the available space:

```
$ lsblk
xvda                              202:0    0   500G  0 disk
└─xvda1                           202:1    0   100G  0 part /
```

```
$ growpart /dev/xvda 1
$ resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```